# Unit test on custom django admin template

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-templates, django-admin

No clue how to deal with this situation.
Recently start unit test with django.
In my project, i have a custom change_list.html to add a button on the admin page.

I'm looking for a unit test which can verify this custom button.
Here is my code in admin.py :

```
class LocationAdmin(OSMGeoAdmin):

    def get_urls(self):
        urls = patterns('', url(
            r'^import/$',
            self.admin_site.admin_view(self.import_process)
        ))

        super_urls = super(LocationAdmin, self).get_urls()

        return urls + super_urls

    def import_process(self, request):
        pass

admin.site.register(Location, LocationAdmin)
```

This code automaticaly load the template in app/admin/app/app/change_list.html
Which is :

```
{% extends "admin/change_list.html" %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% block extrahead %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "css/custom_upload.css" %}">
{% endblock %}
{% block object-tools-items %}
    {{ block.super }}
    <li><a role="button" href="import/" class="btn btn-primary btn-margin-left">Import</a></li>

{% endblock %}
```

But how about when you want to proove that work's with a unit test?
I'm able to test template when i can use a view and the function render_to_string
Like this :

```
response = my_view(HttpRequest())
expected_html = render_to_string(
    'template.html',
    {'arg_key': arg}
)
self.assertEqual(response.content.decode(), expected_html)
```

But here, i don't figure it out how to call the admin view with the associate template part.
Here a start of what i found to add unit test on admin page.

```
class MockRequest(object):
    pass


class MockSuperUser(object):

    def has_perm(self, perm):
        return True

request = MockRequest()
request.user = MockSuperUser()


class ModelAdminTests(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.site = AdminSite()

    def test_admin_import_button_on_location_admin_page(self):
        ma = ModelAdmin(Location, self.site)
        #Here the correct assert ?
```

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be a good idea (probably a better alternative: [using the test client](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/tools/#the-test-client)). But for reference, here is how you can render the changelist_view programmatically directly from the admin method:

```py
from django.contrib.admin import AdminSite, ModelAdmin
from django.test.client import RequestFactory
from django.contrib.admin.templatetags.admin_urls import admin_urlname
from django.shortcuts import resolve_url

class MockUser:
    is_active = True
    is_staff = True

    def has_perm(self, *args):
        return True

url = resolve_url(admin_urlname(MyModel._meta, "changelist"))
request = RequestFactory().get(url)
request.user = MockUser()

class MyAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    change_list_template = "path/to/custom/template/if/needed"

admin = MyAdmin(Work, AdminSite())
html = admin.changelist_view(request).rendered_content
```